# Tensorflow - build cyclic graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, cycle

I'm building TF graph,this is part of my code:

```
class Model:
  def __init__(self, neurons, links, input_neurons_num=4):
    """
    Constructor.
    :param neurons: array list of neurons
    :param input_neurons_num: number of input neurons
    """
    # neuron_id as key and weights entering in it as value
    self.weights = {}
    # neuron_id as key and neurons entering in it as value
    self.connections = {}
    self.graph = None

 def build_graph(self):
     with self.graph.as_default():
        operations = {}

        # create Variables for input vertices
        for neuron_id in self.input_neurons:
            self.inputs[neuron_id] = tf.get_variable(name=str(neuron_id), shape=(),
                                                     initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

        # create input & output vertices
        for neuron_id in self.connections:
            input_neuron_ids = self.connections[neuron_id]

            # weights
            v_weights = tf.constant(self.weights[neuron_id])
            # input vertices
            v_inputs = []

            for input_neuron_id in input_neuron_ids:
                if self.is_input_neuron(input_neuron_id):
                    vertex = self.inputs[input_neuron_id]
                else:
                    # KeyError if input_neuron_id isn't alreay created
                    vertex = operations[input_neuron_id]

                v_inputs.append(vertex)


            # multiply weights and inputs
            mul = tf.multiply(v_inputs, v_weights, str(neuron_id))
```

So I have list of links, where each link has *from_neuron*, *to_neuron* and *weight*. For example: (1,2,3) => *edge*(connection) from 1 to 2 with weight 2.
I want to iterate through all links and based on connections build graph.

At start I know input and output nodes. Idea is to iterate through links and gradually build graph. If there is *node 4*: (1,4,2), (2,4,3.5) I would like to create a *tf.operation* which will multiply output from 1 and its weight(2), output from 2 and its weight(3.5), sum obtain values and pass it forward through network.
But problem is if I have input nodes: 1,2,3, and *node 4* that has connection with etc. *node 7* which is not created yet. It will try to reference node that isn't created yet, and I will get *KeyError*.

Then I tried to skip nodes that are connected with ones that aren't exists yet:

```
deletion = []
        while len(self.connections) > 0:
            for neuron_id in deletion:
                self.connections.pop(neuron_id, None)
            deletion = []
            # create input & output vertices
            for neuron_id in self.connections:
                # same logic with addition:
                deletion.append(neuron_id)
```

And this works, but problem is when I have cycle in graph. This will fall into infinite loop.

Only idea I have to solve this problem is to do this in two passes. In first pass to create all nodes in graph, and in second to replace them with actually values. I thought to use placeholders, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

So any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Building a graph wih a cycle is not (yet?) possible in Tensorflow, because computing the gradient becomes too difficult. The usual approach is to circumvent the problem by "unfolding" the graph a bit, as explained [in the recurrent neural net tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent#truncated_backpropagation). In most deep learning tasks it performs very well. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473787/7456923) another answer explaining this (still in the case of RNNs).

If you want a "pure" cyclic graph, maybe pytorch can help you.

EDIT (02/2020) :

With [TF2.0 and Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn) it's easier to build recurrent networks, which are basically cyclic graphs. However I believe behind the scenes it's still an unfolded graph, not a truly cyclic one.

Comment: But I found some answers, etc. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551389/cyclic-computational-graphs-with-tensorflow-or-theano) which says that cyclic is supported.
I don't need backpropagation, I only want to compute forward pass. Network structure and weights are built with [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies).
A few people have also recommended me pythorch, so I will definitely have a look.